# Task.Run does not work like Thread.start

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I've been developing an application which I need to run some methods as parallel and not blocking. first I used ***Task.Run***, but **IN DEBUG MODE**, I see that the operation blocks and just waits for the result. I do not want this, I want all method , which call in a *foreach loop*, run asynchronously.

```
public async void f()
{
    foreach (var item in childrenANDparents)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => SendUpdatedSiteInfo(item.Host,site_fr));
        // foreach loop does not work until the task return and continues
    }
}
```

So I ***changed the task.run to thread.start*** and it works great!

```
public async void f()
{
    foreach (var item in childrenANDparents)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(() => SendUpdatedSiteInfo(item.Host, site_fr));
        t.Start();
        // foreach loop  works regardless of the method, in debug mode it shows me 
        // they are working in parallel
    }
}
```

Would you explain what is the difference and why ? I expect the same behavior from both code and it seems they are different.

thanks

Comment: `await` does is exactly what it says, it awaits the competition

Comment: OH, I did not know about it , I just thought it runs asynchronously , So if it waits it cannot be in paralell? how can I perform it with task?

Comment: This calls for a `Parallel.ForEach()`, not for `await Task.Run()`. The await is blocking you.

Comment: So I misunderstand the concept of **async await** ,

Comment: It will run asynchronously, but only until the next await. So if you want to run a method asynchronously at the same time you would do `var foo = Task.Run(() => Foo()); Bar(); await foo;`. Now Foo runs alongside Bar and resychronizes at the await. That being said, if you want to run multiple stuff in parallel use Parallel.For/ForEach which will find the proper amount of threads to use and even adjust them accordingly in case of different loads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a simple [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`PLinq`](http://Parallel%20LINQ%20(PLINQ))

```
Parallel.ForEach(childrenANDparents, (item) => 
                            {
                               SendUpdatedSiteInfo(item.Host,site_fr)
                            });
```

To better understand `async` and `await` its best to start reading some docos, its a large topic, but its worth your while

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Answer (score 7):

> I want all method , which call in a foreach loop, run asynchronously.

It seems that you're confusing async/sync calls with *parallelization*.

A quote from MSDN:

> Data parallelism: A form of parallel processing where the same
> computation executes in parallel on different data. Data parallelism
> is supported in the Microsoft .NET Framework by the Parallel.For and
> Parallel.ForEach methods and by PLINQ. Compare to task parallelism.
>
> Asynchronous operation: An operation that that does not block the current thread
> of control when the operation starts.

Let's have a closer look at your code again:

```
foreach (var item in childrenANDparents)
{
    await Task.Run(() => SendUpdatedSiteInfo(item.Host,site_fr));
}
```

The await keyword will cause compiler to create a StateMachine that will handle the method execution.

It's like if you say to compiler:"Start this async operation without blocking any threads and when it's completed - execute the rest of the stuff".

After Task finishes execution this thread will be released and returned to a ThreadPool and it will execute the rest of the code on a first available thread from a ThreadPool and will make attempt to execute it in a thread in which it had started the method execution (unless .ConfigureAwait(false) is used in which case it's more like 'fire and forget' mode when we don't really care which thread will do the continuation).

When you create a separate `Thread` you do parallelism by delegating some code to run in a separate Thread. So depending on the code itself it may or may not be executed *asynchronously*.

It's like if you say to compiler:"Take this piece of work start a new thread and do it there"

If you still want to use Tasks with parallelism you could create an array of tasks in a loop and then wait for all of them to finish execution:

```
var tasks = new[] 
{ 
    childrenANDparents.Select(item=> Task.Run(() => SendUpdatedSiteInfo(item.Host,site_fr)));
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

P.S.

And yes you may as well use `TPL` (Task Parallel Library) and specifically Parallel loops.